# Array of custom class instances in another class crashes compiler

Tags: c++, arrays, class, compiler-errors, nested

This is kind of a strange question but I'm not getting much useful info from the compiler and am wondering what I'm doing wrong.

I have a program (we'll just call it 'main') that includes a class 'world', which itself includes a class 'tile'.  Everything is being included correctly as far as I can tell - I can add an instance of tile as a member of an instance of world and then (via public getter methods) access the data in the tile from main.

The problem occurs when I want to use a multi-dimensional array of tiles as a member of an instance of world - the compiler crashes with the helpful message "cc1plus.exe has stopped working" and the helpful text "[Build Error]  [main.o] Error 1".

I have a parameterless default constructor defined for the tile class (and for the world class as well although I don't think that's relevant.)  I'm not sure at all what else could cause this.  Any insight would be really appreciated.

Ex:
main.cpp

```
#include <world.h>
world newWorld;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
newWorld = world();
}
```

world.h

```
#include <tile.h>
class world {
tile wmap[100][100][10]
public:
world(){
//code that calls the parametized constructor for tile for each element in the array
}
};
```

tile.h

```
class tile {
int temp;
public:
tile(){}
tile(int t){temp = t;}
};
```

I apologize if the answer should be obvious, this is my first foray back into C++ in several years and it seems I've gotten sloppy.

Comment: Have you tried a smaller array? Perhaps you're hitting an internal compiler limit. It seems the limit would be bit low if you are, but worth trying.

Comment: Works for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/423b651b6aff8c8d

Answer (score 0):

For a multi-dimensional array in C++ you need to allocate the space, before you try to use it, in this case probably using new().

See [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: Hmm - would that cause the compiler itself to bomb out though?  It seems like that should cause a build error.  Plus, can you really instantiate private class members in a loop like that?

Comment: And I apologize for a further dumb question but I really want to understand WHY it's not working rather than just what's going wrong: I coded a program to generate random roguelike-style dungeons a while back and this program was meant to clean up and properly encapsulate some of that code - in that case, my map was basically a few multi-dimension char arrays, and I didn't have to do anything specific to get them to work.  Is that just because that was a basic type and this is a class?  For whatever reason I feel like it should be working the same.

Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: I don't have a windows compiler to test this on, speculating ( agree it's strange that the compiler is bombing out) - it could be:

`world newWorld;`

since that will statically create an instance which could then invoke the constructor. 

As to why. Multi-dimensional arrays weren't part of the C/C++ standard, and K&R's example of how to do them actually used malloc. 

As far as C++ is concerned, it's all just memory - so with something like char c[10][10], the area of memory allocated is enough that you might get away with it, if you were lucky with the memory that ended up being overwritten.